# Rate limiting pattern for implementing API throttling for a cloud service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rate-limiting, bandwidth-throttling

I wanted to implement throttling for a set of services provided.
Under peak load,I want to limit or deny services to long running users or users sending huge data or other rules that can be configured even at a later stage.
I plan to use java and spring framework to code this in.

I have read about rate limiting pattern.One possible implementation suggested by stack-overflow post was [Token_bucket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket). the article feels complicated.
Can anyone suggest other alternative approaches or patterns. And good articles describing them.

I also found another pdf from microsoft - [cloud design pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568099.aspx).
But it doesn't provide much on implementing a throttling patterns.But similar article would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I believe we can also use circuit breaker pattern here and put the circuit in an open state once the rate limit is reached.
The circuit will have to reset it to a closed state however.